# HTML position variable

Tags: html, css

I know this is easy with Javascript but... is there any way with just CSS?

Let's say we have two elements (green and red) within a parent one (beige). The red element should be always to the right of the green one, except if the green one (because of the content) is too big to fit the parent in which case the red one will be over the green one (the normal behaviour would be the red element staying to the right of the green one and therefore being hidden because of the overflow of the parent)

In other words: red.x = min(green.x + green.w, beige.x+beige.w-red.w)

[image: Example image]

For more info, here's the concrete HTML:

```
<div class="beige" style="width:250px"> <!-- parent with a given width (unknown until the page is rendered) & overflow hidden -->
  <a class="green"> <!-- link with display:inline -->
    content
    <em class="red"></em> <!-- actually a button, 15 px width -->
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** @kyledws answer is awesome but I'll update the question with more info (needed things) such as:

- red is only displayed when green:hover (that's why it's inside green)
- you don't know beige width in CSS (in the *real world* beige is inside a  with defined width but not known until the page is rendered)
- green content is a variable length text, and the reason of red being pushed
- if the green content does not fit into the parent, it should show the ellipsis (text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden)
- must work in IE8+

Comment: Can `em.red` be moved outside of `a.green` or can the structure not be changed at all?

Comment: For this application, semantically it's better to have the em inside the a because in the real world, the em it's a button to open the link in a new window, but I guess you can move it out if it helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're able to wrap the content inside `<a>` in a `span` then try this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="beige">
    <a class="green" href="#">
      <span class="content">This is some text.</span><em class="red"></em>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.beige {
  background-color: #EBDFA0;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid #EBDFA0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.green {
  background-color: #4CA73D;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: underline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 364px;
  top: -50%;
}

.red {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
}
```

Essentially the `<a class="green">`, `<span class="content">` and `<em class="red">` need to be `display: inline-block` and the `<span class="content">` has to be `width: 100%` with a `max-width` of the different between the `<div class="beige">` and the `<em class="red"` minus any additional padding/margin/border etc. (So in this example, `max-width: 364px`) By setting a width on the `span` you force the `em` outside of it's container but by setting a `max-width` you stop the `em` from flowing outside of the main wrapper.

Here is a [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/kyledws/pen/rCEBu) link to an example.

(Note: Most of the CSS above is just to make the example look like your images.)

**UPDATE:**

1. To show or hide the `<em class="red">` add the `:hover` pseudo-class to `.beige` and visibility or opacity to `.red`. (Use opacity if you want to use a transition.)

   ```
   .red {
     opacity: 0;
   }

   .beige:hover .red {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   ```
2. Because the width of `<div class="beige">` is unknown you can't use CSS to set `max-width` on `<span class="content">`.

   (The 100% in `max-width: calc(100% - 28px)` is width of `<a class="green">` not `<div class="beige">`. I couldn't hack it with pseudo-elements, positioning, floats or different display types like flex either.)

   The way around this is to fix the `max-width` of the `<span class="content">` in CSS (as is shown above) or use Javascript to detect the width of `<div class="beige">` and then set the `max-width`.

   ```
   content.style.maxWidth = beige.clientWidth - red.clientWidth + "px";
   ```

I updated the [example](http://codepen.io/kyledws/pen/rCEBu) with visibility and Javascript versions.

Also, I added `position: absolute` to `.red` so `<span class="content">` doesn't have empty space on the right.

Comment: Awesome answer!
The codepen.io also works like a charm.

Just a thing: what if you can't know the beige width at the CSS time? You can get it by javascript and update the max-width, but again, is there any CSS-only way?

Comment: CSS calc is not supported by IE8, but anyways I'm gonna accept your answer because it can be useful for other people, as it's very complete!
Anyawys, feel free to improve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way that you can handle this in just CSS. I have setup a jsbin with a example. I don't have a fancy slider so you will need to use the inspector tool to resize the width or do it manually.

Basically I set up a dive as a table. Because you can't drop to different rows the right most column is forced to collapse but leaves the block visible because it is position absolute. The size of the container is based on the  block which has been changed to a inline block to maintain the coloration and push its parent to become larger. Excuse me not making the styles match exactly what you had int he graphics.

http://jsfiddle.net/93u5E/3/

HTML

```
    <div class="beige">
     <div class="table">
      <!-- parent with a given width & overflow hidden -->
    <ul>
        <li><a class="green"> <!-- link with display:inline -->
    content
  </a>
        </li>
        <li><em class="red"></em> 
            <!-- actually a button, 15 px width -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.beige {
    background-color:grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:no-wrap;
}

.table{
    display:table;
}

ul {
    display:table-row;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
}

li:last-child{
    width:30px;
}
.green {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
.red {
    border:3px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px
}
li:hover + li .red{
height:20px;
}
```

***Updating to include hover**

Comment: If the content continue expanding, in the end the red element it's "pushed" and becomes invisible :S
Also, the "nowrap" is actually "nowrap".

I updated your fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/93u5E/4/
BTW you don't need a slider to change the length of the green layer,  just modify the content text.